# Sumo multiple select dropdown after the select dropdown click on outside select dropdown value

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, sumoselect.js

I have used the Sumo select dropdown. When drop-down is closed, but click on  the drop-down, then selects the drop-down values, because values are hiding, but make select See in below attached screen shot.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

I have used the Sumo Select for this dropdown so how can I Solve this problem.

Here the css are:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue generate because of in the css "**height: auto**" the height update the 0px (**height: 0**) then it is work properly, When we click below the dropdown do not select any option.

[image]